# Unable to Populate select-option tag using g:select in Groovy

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to run the sample Collab-Todo application as in book Beginning Groovy and Grails,page no.123 (Author:Christopher M. Judd,Joseph Faisal Nusairat,and James Shingler Publication:Apress and Edition:2008). Here is my User.groovy file:

```
package collab.todo

class User {

    String userName
    String firstName
    String lastName
    static hasMany = [todos: Todo, categories: Category]
    static constraints = {
        userName(blank:false,unique:true)
        firstName(blank:false)
        lastName(blank:false)
    }
    String toString () {
        "$lastName, $firstName"
    }
}
```

The UserController.groovy is as Follows:

```
package collab.todo

class UserController {

    def scaffold = User
    def login = {

    }
    def handleLogin = {
        def user = User.findByUserName(params.userName)
        if (!user) {
            flash.message = "User not found for userName: ${params.userName}"
            redirect(action:'login')
        }
        session.user = user
        redirect(controller:'todo')
    }
    def logout = {
        if(session.user) {
            session.user = null
            redirect(action:'login')
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to create,read,update or delete the User table as usual.Here is a sample screenshot of my User view:
[image: The User List]
In the scaffolding view, I am trying to show the list of all the users in a drop-down(as per the book) using following snippet inside the user/login.gsp:

```
<g:select name='userName' from="${User?.list()}"
               optionKey="userName" optionValue="userName"></g:select>
```

But what I am getting in the login page is a dropdown with no values populated:
Here is the screenshot of the login page:
[image: The user/login.gsp view]

In case I change

```
from="${User?.list()}"
```

to

```
from="${User.list()}"
```

I am getting a NullPointerException. So any clues what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `User` class could not be found from your view.

Try one of the following:

Add the import statement to your view.

```
<%@ page import="collab.todo.User" %>
```

Or use the fully qualified name within `from` attribute.

```
from="${collab.todo.User.list()}"
```

The best practice would be to pass the list of users from the controller:

```
def login = {
    [users: User.list()]
}
```

And use the collection within your view

```
from="${users}"
```